# Finding the mass of bed/Patient

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, torque, statics

One of my friends has a problem and we don't know how to get this done,

We want to to know the mass of a patient who is laying on a bed. One scales was put under the foot of a bed and weighed 232kg and the other under the head of the bed and weighed 220kg. The centre mass of the patient is 0.8 meters from the foot of the bed. What is the mass of the patient?

Comment: The problem is formulated very oddly. "under the foot of the bed". A bed usually has four of them. Next: " under the head", what is that? One of the posts at the head end? What about the other posts when one is on the scale? Does one of the other posts "float" ?

Comment: @Georg: i have reworded the question.

Comment: Still not clear: are those scales under the posts at the same time or in consecution? And are they placed under posts on the same side of the bed or diametrally? What about symmetry of bed/patient?

Comment: Constitutive and diametrically.

Comment: I just tried to look up the same question- it's from a study course for the GAMSAT (medicine exam) The second half of this video explains it-
https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/torque-angular-momentum/torque-tutorial/v/moments-part-2

Comment: the video is interesting, but the problem set above is incomplete, no length of bed is given, for example, or weight of bed, numbers that are given in the video.

Comment: see video in @shazbaz answer. you have not given enough input values to solve the problem. one has to guess at the weight of the bed and the length of the bed.

Answer (score 3):

Dear Omeid, this is a homework problem, right? I think we shouldn't be answering the question "explicitly".

But let me mention a hint: if you assume that the data are enough to calculate a unique answer, do you think that the information about the length of the bed may be relevant? You want to get a result in kilograms - and there are two pieces of information in kilograms and one in centimeters. To get a result in kilograms, may the figure involving centimeters matter if you require that the result has the right units?

This argument is called "dimensional analysis".

Now, imagine that you put both scales under the bed simultaneously: one of them is under the foot and one of them is under the head - at the same moment. How much do you think that those scales will show in this case? How can you determine the *total* ;-) mass of the bed using this measurement?

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer Lubos, but this is not homework cause I haven't studied this kind of problems and i even don't know what they are called, can you please tell me what rules and formulas will help me with the problem, I might work it out.

Comment: To all those who downvoted this question and decided to close it: This is neither off-topic nor a homework question. As user58616 said, this is a GAMSAT practise question and in those groups, it is a challenging and oft discussed question that unfortunately we have not many places to get help for. Sorry, but not sorry for saying this: I (and others, I have proof) are sick of our questions here on stackE being downvoted or closed. This is a place for intellectual discussion, not patter, which unfortunately other forums are full of, hence is our only place to post these to get useful feedback.